# How to make Bluetooth tethering work?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, bluetooth-tethering

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Lollipop) and a Visual Elite Prestige 10Q tablet (Kit-Kat rooted with KingRoot), and I'd like to be able to use Bluetooth tethering to let the tablet share the phone's data connection.  Wifi tethering works fine, but it creates a heavy draw on the phone's battery to run both the cellular and wifi radio systems; as I understand it, Bluetooth uses much less battery than wifi (less power required to transmit, hence the shorter range).

Unfortunately, even though I went through the process in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49852/android-to-android-bluetooth-tether) the tablet was unable to see the internet connection via the phone.  The two devices are paired, and I've used the phone's Bluetooth for months to play music in my car.  How can I trouble shoot this and get the connection working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, the other question linked in the question above is very similar, but for older versions of Android.  I did finally manage to connect my phone and tablet after finding android weasel's answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30171/does-bluetooth-tethering-not-work-or-am-i-doing-it-wrong?rq=1).  Apparently, the prompts and status messages are poorly designed, but once I understood what I was supposed to see, I got the connection working.  Now, I can tether my tablet to my phone in under a minute, and use the larger screen and keyboard online anywhere I have cell service.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you want to share Internet from Mobile to your tablet using your phone's Bluetooth tethering.

**So first lets understand a little bit about Bluetooth services**: A device which need to access internet via Bluetooth from other device should have **Bluetooth PAN** Service (BT Personal Area Networking) installed/enabled. While the device offering the internet should have the **Bluetooth DUN** Service (BT Dial-up-networking Service) installed/enabled.

**How Connection is established:**
Device with (with BT PAN) establish a wireless dialup connection by dialing a certain code (#99 for GSM devices & #777 for CDMA devices) required to make use of the modem of the internet providing device (equipped with BT DUN). If all goes well connection is established.

**Your Case**:
Since most of the mobile phones and tablets are only equipped with BT-DUN Service and not with BT-PAN Service.. Your tablet is not able to establish the internet connection using your phone's mobile data service. But they can however do other BT exchanges using BT FTP (file Transfer) BT Audio (for headphone/voice) etc.

Since most of the PC's and Laptop does have this BT PAN service enabled, they are able to use the BT tethering from devices offering it.

**Solution for You:**
The most hassle free and easiest solution for you is to use Mobile Phone's WiFi Hotspot for sharing internet to your tablet. this should work well, provided u arent using a illegally unlocked phone (as hotspot functionality gets disabled in some unlock cases like this)

Hope that answer your query. If you still require any help feel free to let us know, we are always here to help :)

Comment: As noted in the question, the phone has BT tethering installed, and the tablet is paired and recognizes the phone, allowing me to go through the process in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Obviously I know your phone has BT Tethering Installed.. Thou it was too descriptive, you still didn't even tried to understand what was explained in my answer, about the various BT services & their dependencies. I've marked it clearly with technical facts, why its not possible using it on tablet. As you repeatedly mentioned that "devices are paired" So, dude, pairing is just an allowance from devices to device to be able to connect various offered BT services. 

One should think twice before marking a technically appropriate answer as (-ive) that too just because they didn't understood it :(

Comment: "why it's not possible using it on tablet."  And you obviously didn't read my own answer above -- which said I got it working after I understood what the check boxes on the tablet side actually did.  There are multiple reasons to prefer BT tethering over wifi from a phone hotspot, and your only solution is to use wifi instead.